# Persist items using a POST request within a Pipeline

Tags: scrapy

I want to persist items within a Pipeline posting them to a url.

I am using this code within the Pipeline

```
class XPipeline(object):
def process_item(self, item, spider):     
    log.msg('in SpotifylistPipeline', level=log.DEBUG)   

    yield FormRequest(url="http://www.example.com/additem, formdata={'title': item['title'], 'link': item['link'], 'description': item['description']})
```

but it seems it's not making the http request.

- Is it possible to make http request from pipelines? If not, do I have to do it in the Spider?
- Do I need to specify a callback function? If so, which one?
- If I can make the http call, can I check the response (JSON) and return the item if everything went ok, or discard the item if it didn't get saved?

As I final thing, is there a diagram that explains the flow that Scrapy follows from beginning to end? I am getting slightly lost which what gets called when. For instance, if Pipelines returned items to Spiders, what do Spiders do with those items? What's after a Pipeline call?

Many thanks in advance

Migsy

Answer (score 4):

You can inherit your pipeline from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.media.MediaPipeline and yield Requests in 'get_media_requests'. Responses are passed into 'media_downloaded' callback.

Answer (score 3):

[Quote](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/item-pipeline.html#process_item):

> This method is called for every item pipeline component and must
>   either return a Item (or any descendant class) object or raise a
>   DropItem exception. Dropped items are no longer processed by further
>   pipeline components.

So, only spider can yield a request with a callback.
Pipelines are used for processing items.

You better describe what do you want to achieve.

> is there a diagram that explains the flow that Scrapy follows from beginning to end

[Architecture overview](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/architecture.html#overview)

> For instance, if Pipelines returned items to Spiders

Pipelines do not return items to spiders. The items returned are passed to the next pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done easily by using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library. If you don't want to use another library then look into [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).

```
import requests

class XPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):       
        r = requests.post("http://www.example.com/additem", data={'title': item['title'], 'link': item['link'], 'description': item['description']})
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return item
        else:
            raise DropItem("Failed to post item with title %s." % item['title'])
```